# Beam.io.WriteToPubSub throws error "The given pcoll PDone[WriteToPubSub/Write/NativeWrite.None] is not a dict, an iterable or a PCollection"

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm getting an error whenever I use "WriteToPubSub". The code below is me trying to debug the issue. My actual code is trying to take data from failures of WriteToBigQuery in order to push it to a deadletter pubsub topic. But when I tried to do that I kept encountering the error below.
I am running Apache Beam 2.27, Python 3.8

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.runners.interactive.interactive_runner import InteractiveRunner
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigtableio import WriteToBigTable
from apache_beam.runners import DataflowRunner
import apache_beam.runners.interactive.interactive_beam as ib
from apache_beam.options import pipeline_options
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
import google.auth
import json
import pytz


# Setting up the Apache Beam pipeline options.
options = pipeline_options.PipelineOptions(flags=[])

# Sets the project to the default project in your current Google Cloud environment.
_, options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).project = google.auth.default()

# Sets the Google Cloud Region in which Cloud Dataflow runs.
options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).region = 'asia-east1'

# Sets the job name
options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).job_name = 'data_ingest'

# IMPORTANT! Adjust the following to choose a Cloud Storage location.
dataflow_gcs_location = '[REDACTED]'

# Dataflow Staging Location. This location is used to stage the Dataflow Pipeline and SDK binary.
options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).staging_location = '%s/staging' % dataflow_gcs_location

# Dataflow Temp Location. This location is used to store temporary files or intermediate results before finally outputting to the sink.
options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).temp_location = '%s/temp' % dataflow_gcs_location

# The directory to store the output files of the job.
output_gcs_location = '%s/output' % dataflow_gcs_location

ib.options.recording_duration = '1m'

# The Google Cloud PubSub topic for this example.
topic = "[REDACTED]"
output_topic = "[REDACTED]"
subscription = "[REDACTED]"
deadletter_topic = "[REDACTED]"


class PrintValue(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        print(element)
        return [element]

p = beam.Pipeline(InteractiveRunner(),options=options)
data = p | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=topic) | beam.ParDo(PrintValue()) | beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=deadletter_topic)

ib.show(data, include_window_info=False)
```

The error given is

```
ValueError: The given pcoll PDone[WriteToPubSub/Write/NativeWrite.None] is not a dict, an iterable or a PCollection.
```

Can someone spot what the problem is?
No matter what I do, WriteToPubSub says it's receiving PDone.

EDIT:
If i use p.run(), I get the following error instead:

```
'PDone' object has no attribute 'to_runner_api'
```

In both cases, the pipeline does not try to run, it immediately errors out.

EDIT:
I've realised the problem

```
p = beam.Pipeline(InteractiveRunner(),options=options)
```

It is this line. If I remove the interactiverunner everything works. Not sure why

Answer (score 2):

### Beam Terminology

Apache Beam has some base concepts, that we should adhere to while leveraging the power of this programming model.

**Pipeline**

In simple terms, a pipeline is a series of tasks for a desired output. It can be as simple as a linear flow or could have a complex branching of tasks. The fundamental concept is read from input source(s), perform some transformations and emit to output(s).

Mathematically, beam pipeline is just a *Directed Acyclic Graph* of tasks.

**PCollection**

In simple terms, PCollections is an *immutable* bag of elements which could be distributed across machines. Each step in a beam pipeline will have it's input and output as a PCollection (apart from sources and sinks)

PCollection is a powerful distributed data structure that a beam pipeline operates on. It could be bounded or unbounded based on your source type.

**PTransforms**

In simple terms, Transforms are the operations of your pipleine. It provides processing logic and this logic is applied to each element of one or more input of  PCollections.

Example : `PTransform<PCollection<X>,PCollection<Y>> will transform X to Y.`

Based on processing paradigm, beam provides us multiple core transforms - ParDo, GroupByKey, Flatten, Combine etc.

**I/O Transforms**

When you create a pipeline one need a data source to read data  such as a file or a database. Likewise, you want to emit your result data to an external storage system such as topic or an object store. The transforms which deal with External Input and Output are I/O Transforms.

Usually for an external source, you will have the following

- Source : A PTransform to read data from the external system. This will read from
  an external system(like file, db). It excepts a PBegin (pipeline entry point) and return a PCollection.

  PTransform<PBegin,PCollection>

  **This would be one of the entry points of your pipeline.**
- Sink : A PTransform that will output data to an external system. This will write to an external system(like topic, storage). It excepts a PCollection  and return a PDone (pipeline entry point).

  PTransform<PCollection,PDone>

  **This would be one of the exit points of your pipeline.**

*Combination of a source and sink is an I/O Connector like RedisIO, PubSubIO etc. Beam provides multiple in-built connectors and one can write a custom one also.*

There are still various concepts and extenions of the above, that allow users to program complex requirements that could be run on different runners. This is what makes Beam so powerful.

### Solution

In your case, ib.show(data, include_window_info=False) is throwing the below error

```
ValueError: The given pcoll PDone[WriteToPubSub/Write/NativeWrite.None] is not a dict, an iterable or a PCollection.
```

[Source Code](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/_modules/apache_beam/runners/interactive/interactive_beam.html#Recordings)

Because your data contains result of beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=deadletter_topic) which is a sink and returns a PDone not a PCollection.

For your use case of BQ Writing Failures to PubSub, you could follow something below

```
     data = beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=topic) | 'Write to BQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery( ...)
        
    (data['beam.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryWriteFn.FAILED_ROWS'] 
              | 'publish failed' >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=deadletter_topic)
```

However, if this does not solve your issue posting the code would be useful or else you could write a custom PTransform with output tags for writing to BQ and to return failures(via tuple tags) for publising to PubSub.

P.S. : [WriteToBigQuery](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.html#WriteToBigQuery) is not a sink, but a custom PTransform that writes to big query and returns failures.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing explanation on the topic. Its so well written.
I've tried your solution though, and I'm still getting the error. Would you be able to work based on the simple case I've written in the question above and show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I've realised the problem
p = beam.Pipeline(InteractiveRunner(),options=options)
It is this line. If i remove the interactiverunner everything works. Not sure why

Comment: And your code above is right, the sink cannot return a value

Comment: I would suggest you not to use interactive runner apart from basic learning. It is an experimental module and should use DirectRunner for development purpose. If we want to debug interactive runner, could you post the updated code of this simple case and complete error trace. For direct and dataflow runner, you could refer to https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/a1d23b5cda0f32d895cb1f790774d8a1